# Which class does the parsing and query building in spring data JPA repository?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, crud-repository

I have read this line in spring docs "The query builder mechanism built into the Spring Data repository infrastructure", can anyone please tell which class exactly does this query building part in spring?

Comment: did you try to download the source code and find out yourself?

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [`org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/main/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/query/JpaQueryCreator.java) and also at [`org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeQuery`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/main/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/query/PartTreeJpaQuery.java).
The former does the actual construction of the query.
The latter holds all the pieces together: The parsed `PartTree` containing the structure of the method name, arguments, the processing of results and so on.

Comment: Follow-up question: On startup the `QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor` creates a `Map<Method, RepositoryQuery>` of queries by "inspecting" the Spring Data repositories. Is it possible to access/list this kind of queries programmatically? Analogous to `NamedQuery`s like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614906/list-of-all-namedqueries-in-jpa. Motivation is to create a convenient way to search for the usage of certain fields...