# How query method of Spring Data JPA generate query?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

When a method is created under a specific rule of Spring Data JPA, a method that calls the corresponding query is created.

For example,

```java
public interface CustomerJpaRepository implements JpaRepository<Customer, Long>{

    public List<Customer> findByName(String name);
}
```

findByName() generate the query similar to one below.

```sql
select * from Customer where name = name;
```

I am curious about this principle. To be precise, **I'm curious about the code that parses this method and turns it into a query.**

I looked at the code of the **SimpleJpaRepository** class that implements **JpaRepository**, but could not find a clue. (Of course, there is a possibility that I did not find it).

In summary, when a method consisting of specific words is declared in JpaRepository, **I am curious about the code that actually executes this method internally**. More specifically, **I'd like to see the code that makes this method works.**

If there is no code to do this internally (I personally doubt it's possible...), I want to know how it is implemented in detail, if there is a link or material that explains the principle or internal process, please share related references.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68432235/which-class-does-the-parsing-and-query-building-in-spring-data-jpa-repository

Comment: @JensSchauder
Thank you for additional explanation :)

Answer (score 6):

The parsing logic for creating queries from spring-data repository method names is currently mainly declared in the package [`org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/tree/main/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/repository/query/parser).

Basically, a repository method name string is parsed into a [`PartTree`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/main/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/repository/query/parser/PartTree.java), which contains [`Part`s](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/main/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/repository/query/parser/Part.java) representing defined abstract query criteria.

The `PartTree` can then be used to create a more specific query object, e.g. with a [`JpaQueryCreator`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/main/spring-data-jpa/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/query/JpaQueryCreator.java), or a [`RedisQueryCreator`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/main/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/repository/query/RedisQueryCreator.java), depending on the type of repository.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check the links in your comments :)

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to check this [Query Creation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) spring doc
It explains the rules of how the method convert into a query.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I already read this article, What I'm looking for is the code that makes the query method work.

Comment: The docs only show us how to use it, but NOT show us how it is implemented behind the scene

Comment: I think that Spring will use reflection to create queries based on the method name at run time, here is a reference: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/java-reflection-api-how-spring-uses-shivangam-soni/